# Loop through a local database with a value from an array, function inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate through an array using the "TimeStamp" value from each object in that array to return the associated values from a local DB. This below works perfectly for a single iteration if I simply use myArray[0] but as soon as I try and turn it into a loop it doesn't work. I know there's some peculiarity about functions inside loops but don't know what the work around/fix is.

```
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {

    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE entryreference = '"+myArray[x].TimeStamp+"' ", [], function(tx,results){

            var tempArray = [];
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

            var tempObject = {
            "Value": results.rows.item(i).value
            }

            tempArray.push(tempObject);

            }

            myArray[x].embeddedArray = tempArray;


            });

      };
```

Comment: Could you test my answer and put a comment saying if it's working or not? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a temporary scope to the code inside loop for each iteration. Previously, problem was with the value of x. The same mysql query for x=myArray.length-1 was being executing myArray.length times. I think it's fixed with this...

```
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {

   (function(x){
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry reference = '"+myArray[x].TimeStamp+"' ", [], function(tx,results){

        var tempArray = [];
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

        var tempObject = {
        "Value": results.rows.item(i).value
        }

        tempArray.push(tempObject);

        }

        myArray[x].embeddedArray = tempArray;


        });
     })(x);
  };
```

Comment: @Jared, I gave a temporary scope to the code inside loop for each iteration. Previously, problem was with the value of x. The same mysql query for x=myArray.length-1 was being executing myArray.length times. I think it's fixed with this... Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Seems to work nicely, can anyone explain the down votes here?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you succeed to correct your code, it is terribly inefficient, since you are running an SQL query for each value in `myArray`.

You have to do this in two steps:

1. building the WHERE part of your query by iterating, probably using an `IN` condition.
2. Executing and processing your query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable "x" is shared by all the callback functions created in the loop, and by the time the callbacks are actually invoked the value of "x" will be one greater than the length of your array. To get around that problem, you have to encapsulate the construction of the callback functions with *another* function so that each callback has a reference to the "embedded" array to be built:

```
function makeCallback(target) {
    return function(tx, results) {

        var tempArray = [];
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            var tempObject = {
                "Value": results.rows.item(i).value
            }

            tempArray.push(tempObject);
        }
        target.embeddedArray = tempArray;
    };
}

for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE entryreference = '" + myArray[x].TimeStamp + "' ", [],
        makeCallback(myArray[x]));
};
```

Each callback gets a reference to the element of "myArray" that is to be updated with the query results. That "target" parameter will be distinct for each callback.

Comment: Below answer with down votes seems to work, would you know why?

Comment: @OliverJ90 it works because it does essentially the same thing as my answer.